# Converting char arrays with literal escape sequences into char

Tags: c, char, escaping, cstring, arrays

I have a C tokenizer library I'm using for a personal project.

It returns escaped characters as a char array of literals. So for example the string "\n" gets returned as this char array:

[][n]

Instead of this (desired) array:

[\n]

Is there an easy way in C to convert the first char array into the second char array without manual parsing?

Here is code example of what I'm after:

```
char test[2];
test[0] = '\\';
test[1] = 'n';
char c = someFunction(test)
printf("A %c B", c);
```

Desired Output:

```
A 
B
```

Is there a way to do this using any obscure tricks or do I need to roll my own function?

Thanks!

Comment: `char someFunction(char *s){ if(s[0]=='\\' && s[1]=='n') return '\n'; return *s;}`

Comment: To do it correctly, you'll want to tokenize the string.  Oh, wait... :)